# How to effectively create material elevation in mainly Inkscape or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, effects, shadows, google-material-design

How to create the material design elevation shadow in Inkscape mainly? Or alternatively in Illustrator?
I have imitated the elevation shadow in Inkscape with the following settings:

[image: My imitation]

There are also two or three wild links on the internet which basically is the same article says to mimic the elevation with a specific edited filter. (See links). 
https://princetonits.com/blog/android/material-shadows-with-inkscape/
http://fav.me/d83zd2q

Those results in this way:
[image: elevation by filter preset]

But I don't understand well how that filter editing works. Not to mention the filter editor's UI is horrible. Is there any method to create consistent elevation shadow everytime and whose process is easier to understand than inkscape's filter editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking for an alternative to the drop shadow filter, you could use a black filled rectangle, moved under the button using *Lower Selection to Bottom*, and move it to the desired position .  The you can apply a blur to it, and reduce the opacity.

[image]

To finish, you could group the button and the shadow.

Comment: Additionally: If you just couldn't find the drop shadow filter, look in Filters > Shadows and Glows > Drop shadow. No filter editing required, just drag the sliders (you can use the preview option to preview the result).

Comment: @Billy:  Yes, I also used that method for the blue boxes. I was trying to understand the filter preset and I see it combined two shadow properties like material shadows in css. So I was asking if there are any easier way to replicate a more natural shadow by combining.
Yes Drop shadow works fine but it lacks the ability to shrink the shadow sideways which I can do with a blurred box.

Comment: Ah, you meant to squash the shadow, so it's narrower than the original? Yes, a blurred rectangle will be the quickest way to do this.